# Table converter integer to image

Tags: vaadin

I am fairly new to Vaadin and am creating a small application. Here I display a table with some columns. In one of the columns I have an integer which, depending on its value, I wish to show an image in that cell.

I have been looking onto table converters but have not find what I am looking for. Could someone help me on the road to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a column generator.

```
    table.addGeneratedColumn("imageNr", new Table.ColumnGenerator() {
        @Override
        public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
            Integer i = (Integer) source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("imageNr").getValue();
            Resource res = getImageResource(i); // get the resource depending the integer value 
            return new Image(null, res);
        }
    });
```

The column id "imageNr" on the first line doesn't have to be the same as the item property id, but if it is it replaces the integer column in the table and also makes this column sortable according to the underlying integer value.